# Why doesnt the value of the pointer head change after i call the function?

Tags: c, list, pointers

I am currently learning lists and i am trying to write a function that insert a struct in the first position of the list .I dont get why head->age returns  2 even if  after the calling of the function

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    
       typedef struct person{
    
             int age;
             struct person* nextnode;
    
       }person;
    
       //void insert_end(person*p,int x);

       void insert_start(person*point,int x);
    
       int main(){
    
       person*head=NULL;
    
       person p1={2,NULL};
       person p2={5,NULL};
       head=&p1;
       p1.nextnode=&p2;
    
       insert_start(head,14);
    
       printf("%d\n",head->age);
    
       return 0;
      }
    
    
      void insert_start(person*point,int x){
    
         person*newnode=malloc(sizeof(person));
         newnode->age=x;
         newnode->nextnode=p;
    
    
         point=newnode;
    
      }
```